# Angular Authentication Service - TOKEN BASED

Tags: angular, authentication, access-token

In my `AuthenticationService` I have:

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

login(username: string, password: string) {                                
    return this.http.post<any>
    (`${environment.apiUrl}/token`, "grant_type=password&username="+username+"&password="+password).pipe(map(user => {                
            // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response                      
            if (user && user.token) {
                // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));                    
            }                                
            return user;
        }));
}
```

In `if (user && user.token)` ... `user.token` returns `undefined` and then doesn't create the `currentUser` localStorage.

If I write only: `if (user)` ... it works and generates the access_token like this:

```
access_token:"eiGcvwEa0SsL0xml2Y5BcnR5W1g-vTniUB96YPFsnWe7AwG-pEmtLaOf1nurnYOFFJ-qpax5QceWD9qkEtXJIWU91DFvDwEOrrRqIrb1-gBFnspTk6dE6YjIXpZqkcA1JHWJezQx0dfqBINhZ08qocfIrqK0IqqOvguRh9-PUJCPRMg4JaYh3CJGAZVqbFi8WiO4OwRwrBVqXXGWSHqoCUgHxWDYolCZE7axCLDdbTcbCz2IluemsA0kdmvyQ2laub3iELFN-5m7dAvpCYtFvHjt2qkYijH_v2E3uV5dux5e_txj4XSTzoT8kikoCn7I"
expires_in:59
refresh_token:"c723ec64-c90e-482d-8292-390214d5324b"
token_type:"bearer"
```

I need to get the token from `user.token` but I don't know where I'm wrong.

Comment: Because the property is `access_token` not `token`. Try `if(user && user.access_token)`

Comment: it was very simple. THANK YOU SO MUCH!!

Comment: I will post it as an answer, so you can select it

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the `user` object has a property `token`? (try logging `user` to the console).

Maybe the property you're looking for is `access_token`.

Answer (score 0):

Because the property is `access_token` not `token`. Try `if(user && user.access_token)`